# How to switch <b-button> text after click with unique id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`. I have a `b-button` in my template where I want to switch its text after clicking on it.

I'm passing my generated unique `item.id` to my script, but this is not working out in the case that every `b-button text` will be changed and not only the one I'm clicking. What is the problem in here?

You should be able to copy, paste the code and it should work out.

Please notice that it's just a replica of my code shortened on needed code, so the code should not be changed this much.

My template:

```html
<div v-for="item in inputs" :key="item.id">
  <b-button @click="changeText(item)">{{btnText}}</b-button>
</div>

<b-button @click="addInput">Add Input</b-button>
```

My script:

```
data() {
  return {
    collapsed: [true],
    id: null,
    inputs: [{id: 0}],
    btnText: "It's false",
  }
},

methods: {
  changeText(item) {
    this.collapsed[item.id] = !this.collapsed[item.id]

    if(this.collapsed[item.id] === true) {
      this.btnText = "It's true"
    }
    else if(this.collapsed[item.id] === false) {
      this.btnText = "It's false"
    }
  },

  addInput() {
    this.inputs.push({
      id: this.id += 1, 
    })
    this.collapsed.push(true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of having separate arrays to store the different fields, move them into the `inputs[]` object array, so that each `item` in the `v-for` has its own `id`, `collapsed`, and `btnText`.
2. Then update `changeText()` to refer to the fields within the `item` argument.
3. Also update the template to use the `item.btnText` field.

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{ id: 0, collapsed: true, btnText: `It's true` }], 1️⃣
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeText(item) {
      item.collapsed = !item.collapsed 2️⃣

      if (item.collapsed) {
        item.btnText = `It's true`
      } else {
        item.btnText = `It's false`
      }
    },
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({ 1️⃣
        id: this.id++,
        collapsed: true,
        btnText: `It's true`,
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in inputs" :key="item.id">   3️⃣
      <b-button @click="changeText(item)">{{ item.btnText }}</b-button>
    </div>

    <b-button @click="addInput">Add Input</b-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-toggle-item-props-in-vfor?file=src/components/MyButtons.vue)

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed! - at least I don't know why I have made it like this before because I've still done it on some other functions before.. but thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an object for btnText like

```
data() {
  return {
    collapsed: [false],
    id: null,
    inputs: [{id: 0}],
    btnText: {0: "It's false"} //Change added
  }
},

methods: {
  changeText(item) {
    this.collapsed[item.id] = !this.collapsed[item.id]

    if(this.collapsed[item.id] === true) {
      this.btnText[item.id] = "It's true"; //Change added
    }
    else if(this.collapsed[item.id] === false) {
      this.btnText[item.id] = "It's false"; //Change added
    }
  },

  addInput() {
    this.inputs.push({
      id: this.inputs.length, // Change added
    })
    this.btnText[this.inputs.length] = 'It's false';  //Change added
    this.collapsed.push(true);

  }
}
```

and your template should be like

```
<div v-for="item in inputs" :key="item.id">
  <b-button @click="changeText(item)">{{btnText[item.id]}}</b-button> <!-- Change added -->
</div>

<b-button @click="addInput">Add Input</b-button>
```

Comment: it only works when I do following: Click on Button -> Add Input than it will be updated, only clicking on button is not enough..

Comment: Thats becoz initially you are setting `true` in `collapsed` array

Comment: set that as false for first button initially

Comment: Unfortunately, this change does not change anything.. Clicking on my button does not change anything, only when I add a new Input, than it will be changed

Comment: if I console.log everything works fine. The only problem is that it will not updated in my template.. is this some lifecycle problem?